# Posftix configuration with antispam

Tags: postfix

I have postfix with anti spam and when anti spam returns status 554 (spam mail) to postfix the mail is bounced to the sender.

Is there a way to decide another action for postfix for 554 like reject.

Ant another question is:
is it possible to look for the domain of the sender and decide if to bounce or to reject according to the domain (look in some list of domains).

Thanks.

Comment: Don't know Postfix that well - I have to relearn it each time I set it up (not often). However, I'm sure it does. You should NEVER bounce messages as the majority of incoming mail that would trigger a bounce is spam with a fraudulent from address. So if you bounce it, you are adding to global spam problems. You should almost certainly just log and black-hole it.

Comment: that's what I'm trying to do, but can't find how to change bounce to just drop.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your recipient maps are set properly in main.cf or you'll likely backscatter. At least then bouncing won't be so offensive.

For rejecting messages, add an entry to main.cf like:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,
    # permit_sasl_authenticated,
    reject_non_fqdn_sender,
    reject_non_fqdn_recipient, 
    reject_unknown_sender_domain,
    reject_unlisted_recipient,          # !!! should strictly enforce relay_recipient_maps 
    reject_unknown_recipient_domain,    # less strict, probably redundant on most configurations
    reject_unauth_pipelining,
    reject_unauth_destination, 
    reject_invalid_hostname,
    reject_non_fqdn_hostname,
    # check_policy_service unix:private/spf-policy, 
    reject_multi_recipient_bounce
```

Some of those later checks like rejecting non_fqdn_hostname are desirable but maybe problematic or useless on a LAN environment; permit_mynetworks should allow you to work around that. They're toward the end because it's probably CPU-intensive to check DNS. SPF and SASL authentication are desirable, but you don't say whether you use them.

See [postconf configuration](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html).

For more fine-grained control, and to answer your second question, use postfix header checks.  main.cf gets a line like:

```
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
```

Then /etc/postfix/header_checks gets all sorts of regex

```
/^From: "spammer/                                               REJECT
/^Received: from .*\.pubye\.com \(.*\.pubye\.com \[.*\]\)/      REJECT
```

Instead of REJECT, you can do DISCARD and it will be accepted and then just thrown away.  For example to discard a class C sender:

```
/^Received: from .* \[104\.140\.32\..*/                         DISCARD
```

You may want to use dovecot's SIEVE or Courier's maildrop or something to filter spam to a junk folder rather than reject it outright.